# Liferay with struts spring hibernate

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2.0 and creating a portlet with Struts2 + spring 3.5 and hibernate 3 framework

Nothing to worry for me.

But whenever I deploy my portlet in Liferay at that time Following error occurs.. Its not harmful for me. My portlet working what I like.

But I want to remove following error:

> 11:51:39,745 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-12][GZipFilter:81]
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.String    at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.BrowserSnifferImpl.getUserAgent(BrowserSnifferImpl.java:357)

...............

> 11:51:39,745 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-21][GZipFilter:81]
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.String    at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.BrowserSnifferImpl.getUserAgent(BrowserSnifferImpl.java:357)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.BrowserSnifferImpl.isMozilla(BrowserSnifferImpl.java:216)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.BrowserSnifferImpl.isFirefox(BrowserSnifferImpl.java:140)

Why This Error Occured ????

Comment: Finally... I resolve this problem... ** I have added speed-filters-enabled=false ** in **liferay-plugin-package.properties**... And problem solved. This means that I am disabling default configuration in Liferay

Comment: After it its works perfectly....